# Deploying asp.net application(.Net4.0) package on to IIS 6.0

Tags: web-deployment-project, vb.net-2010

I have created a asp.net application project in Visual Studio 2010 (.net 4.0). I had published it using Project-> Build Deployment Package. It generated .zip file along with files having extension " .deply.cmd", ".SetParameters.xml", ".SourceManifest.xml" and readme.txt, in Application (obj\Release\Package) folder

My intension is to host the package on test server which has IIS6.0, Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 Edition service pack 2. It has .net 4.0.

I tried by running the cmd file but its showed me an message as below:

ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value. msdeploy.exe is not found on this machine. Please install Web Deploy before execute the script.

any help pl....

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed WebDeploy on he target server?  If not, try that.  You can find it here: http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy.

If you have and you're still getting the error, it seems that the installer doesn't create the registry key or environment variable that the VS2010-constructed files expect: see [here](http://mynerditorium.blogspot.com/2011/02/case-of-web-deploy-20-and-missing.html).

I opened the registry key at: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\2 took the value of the registry value InstallPath ("C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\" on my machine) and used it to create an environment variable called "MSDeployPath".  After that the .cmd file ran.

Comment: How did you actually create the environmental variable MSDeployPath? I hear if you do this wrong, you can seriously screw up your system. Basically, you added something to your TFS server called "%MSDeployPath%"? Or did you just add MSDeployPath to your PATH?

Comment: I don't have a TFS server.  I just created an environment variable using the System Properties window.